# How to find multi part rar archives, extract them into their directories and remove them if everything successful

Tags: find, rar

I have hundreds of folders with multi part archives inside them.

```
-FOLDER.1
    file.rar
    file.r00
    file.r01
    file.r02
-FOLDER.2
    file.rar
    file.r00
    file.r01
```

I am using the code below to extract them inside their respective folders and to remove them upon successful extraction,

```
flock -n locked -c "find . -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar e -o- {} \; -execdir rm {} \; && find . -name '*.r[:0-9:][:0-9:]' -exec rm {} \;"
```

**The problem** is if something goes wrong, lets say;

- One of the parts of the archive is corrupted,
- Files are not uploaded yet

This script **deletes the multi parts** even though extracting is not successful. **How can improve this script so it deletes rar files and parts if extraction is successful.**
I spend my whole morning to figure this out but so far no success.

Comment: how do you expect the event "Files are not uploaded yet" to be detected ?

Comment: I am depending on successful extraction on that side.

Answer (score 0):

The `rm` commands must be dependent on the result of the `unrar` command where in your example they are all run sequentially whatever happens.

So try something like that instead (on a test directory first!):

```
flock -n locked -c "find . -name '*.rar' -print0 | xargs -0 -I FILE sh -c \"unrar e -o- FILE && rm FILE `basename FILE .rar`.r[:digit:][:digit:]\" "
```

Then the `rm`part is executed only if the `unrar`command finished successfully.

You will need extra quotes if your file names have spaces.

Comment: Sorry but I am strugling to understand this;
Extraction went OK, deleted .rar file but the rest stays. How can I delete the rest of the files "test_file.r[:0-9:]"
rm: cannot remove './test_file.rar.r[:0-9:]': No such file or directory

Comment: I have edited my answer, it should work for all files from .r00 to .r99